# TextView text color in Cell doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with `textView` in each `cell`.
When the user make the action of `Pull to Refresh`, the whole view change it's color, so as the text color of the `textView` in the cell.
**But some cells do not change their color immediately** for some reason, they do finally change their color when I click the `cell` and move to the next view.

Here is an example:
[image]

As you can see, the text color of the first cell is correct, but the two others is still like the old color.

Here is my code:

```
    var colorNumber = 1
    var currentColor = UIColor()
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

func colors() {
    switch colorNumber {
            case 1: currentColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 244/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
            case 2: currentColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 200/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
            default: currentColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 28/255, blue: 37/255, alpha: 1)
    }
            tableView.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! notesTableViewCell
    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.textView.isEditable = false
    cell.textView.isSelectable = false
    cell.textView.text = contentInNotes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textView.textColor = currentColor
    cell.textView.backgroundColor = .clear
}

func refreshColor(sender:AnyObject) {
        switch colorNumber {
        case 1:
            colorNumber = 2
        case 2:
            colorNumber = 3
        case 3:
            colorNumber = 1
        default:
            colorNumber = 1
        }
        colors()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Change Colors")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshColor(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
```

**EDIT:**

> I found out that, for some reason, whenever the number of characters
>   in each cell is more than 4 & in English - it doesn't change it color! There is
>   nothing related to limitation of characters in the code.

Any idea why?

Comment: How are you calling `refreshColor(sender:)`?

Comment: When I 'pull to refresh' the tableView, I added it in the topic

Comment: I don't see problem in this code. May be problem inside cell.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov What kind of information do you want me to provide? In the tableViewCell VC it's just an outlet of the textView in the cell

Comment: I think you have omitted some code when posting the question, because, your code have build time errors. At least provide full code of `cellForRowAt indexPath: ` so that we could help.

Comment: Do you change colour of textView in other methods?

Comment: @FahriAzimov I just added all the code that contain `textView` in `cellForRowAt`.
@AndrewRomanov Nope, just this

Comment: @FahriAzimov - I found out that, for some reason, whenever the number of characters in each cell is more than 4 - it doesn't change it color! There is nothing related to limitation of characters in the code.

Comment: Can you create example project at github? It is extremely interesting!